# position button on the screen in android

Tags: android

hey need some help i tried everything
i want to position my buttons in (x,y) 
i have tried to use b.setX(x) and b.setY(y) but when i use the 2 line the button dosent appear.

tnx for help
my code:

```
b = new Button(MainActivity.this);
                b.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.round_button);
                b.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(100, 100));
                b.setText(String.valueOf(values.get(i).getTable_number()));
                b.setTag(values.get(i).getTable_number());
                b.setId(values.get(i).getTable_number());
    //            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(100, 100);

                float x =values.get(i).getX();
                float y =values.get(i).getY();
                System.out.println("check place " + x+y);

    //            b.setX(x);
    //            b.setY(y);
                MultiTouchListener touchListener = new MultiTouchListener(MainActivity.this);
                b.setOnTouchListener(touchListener);
                main.addView(b);//show button
                View draggableView = b;//the button can move
                draggableView.setOnTouchListener(MainActivity.this);
                tableInfo.close();
```

Comment: We do not normally position widgets directly using absolute pixel coordinates in Android. Why specific problem are you trying to solve this way?

Comment: the buttons are draggable ,i want them to stay the same position i left them